# Jquery post responses 500 error after some time and lastly an 503 error

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, ajax, jquery, 500-internal-error

I'm currently developing a wordpress plugin that fetches product attributes from 3rd API and creates WooCommerce products using these attrs.

I wrote two different jquery post function nestedly. The whole javascript code is as the following:

```
add_action( 'admin_footer', 'my_action_javascript' ); // Write our JS below here
function my_action_javascript() { ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var element = document.getElementById("theBar");
    var width=0;
    var move=2;
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $( "#totally" ).click(function() {
            var data = {
            'action': 'my_action',
            'whatever': 1234
            };

            jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
                console.log(response);
                element.style.width = (width+move) + "%"; 
                element.innerHTML = (width+move) * 1  + "%";
                width = width+move;
                document.getElementById("currprogstatus").textContent="Product infos fetched";
                var info = {
                'action': 'start_addprod',
                'thing': 1658
                };
                var repeat = parseInt(response);
                for (var z = 0; z < repeat ; z++) {

                    jQuery.post(ajaxurl, info, function(response) {
                        console.log(response);
                        element.style.width = (width+move) + "%"; 
                        element.innerHTML = (width+move) * 1  + "%";
                        width= width+move;
                        document.getElementById("currprogstatus").textContent="Woocommerce products are being added";
                    });

                }
            
            });

        });
    });
    </script> <?php
}
```

Maybe it seems unnecessarily confusing to doing this way. But the main purpose here is, doing a backend process and controlling a progress bar synchronously.

Anyway, everything is fine until the 5th ajax response. After that, the progress bar suddenly stops and when I look console bar; I see all other ajax requests responses with 500 error code and the last response is 503 error. Here is the related screenshot:
[image: jquery_500_503_response]

While this happening, the products are being continue to added(until 2000 products) some time more. But then, this process also interrupting couldn't reach the end (3000 products).

I checked execution time and input time values in php.ini and time values are higher more than enough. I'll be grateful if you help.